# GenealogyTree: ancestor approach

Tags: genealogytree, genealogy

The typical approach in building a family tree is the ancestor approach: the direction is from the children to the parents. This approach is the most used because, in a genealogy research, the researcher start from the bottom (usually from himself).

To use this approach with the [genealogytree](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree) package (see the official documentation [here](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree/genealogytree.pdf)), the best solution seems to be the *[subgraph "parent"](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree/genealogytree.pdf#section.4.2)*:

> **parent**: A parent family may contain other parent families. Trees with this construction grow into ancestor direction [...]

With this *type of family* I can easily create a tree like this:

[image: parent-familytree]

The source code of the previous image is this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{incgraph}

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\begin{inctext}

    \begin{genealogypicture}[
    template=database pole,
        processing=database,
        database format=full,
        node size=3cm,
        level size=3.2cm,
        list separators hang,
        place text={\newline}{},
        box={fit basedim=9pt,
            boxsep=2pt,
            segmentation style={solid},
            halign=left,
            before upper=\parskip1pt,
            \gtrDBsex}
        ]

        parent{

            g{name={A. Son}}
            c{name={B. Son}}

            parent{

                g{name={1. Father}}
                c{name={1. Uncle}}

                parent {
                    g{name={1. Grandfather}}
                }

                parent {
                    g{name={1. Grandmother}}
                }
            }

            parent{

                g{name={2. Mother}}
                c{name={2. Uncle}}

                parent {
                    g{name={2. Grandfather}}
                }

                parent {
                    g{name={2. Grandmother}}
                }
            }
        }

    \end{genealogypicture}

\end{inctext}
\end{document}
```

But there is a problem. In the *subgraph "parent"* I can't nest the *subgraphs* *"child"* and *"union"*. From the *[subgraph "parent"](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree/genealogytree.pdf#section.4.2)* section of the official documentation:

[image: subraph-parent-documentation]

So for example, referring to the previous image, I can't add another partner to *Father*, because to do this I need the *subgraph "union"*. And I can't add a family (*Aunt* and *Cousins*) to the *Uncle*, because I need the *subgraph "child"*.

And the *[subgraph "sandlock"](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree/genealogytree.pdf#section.4.5)* doesn't solve the problem, because with this I can add, for example, a family to a *Son*, and nothing else.

Apparently the solution would be to use the *[subgraph "child"](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree/genealogytree.pdf#section.4.3)* instead of *subgraph "parent"* as the main structure of the family tree. But the *subgraph "child"* doesn't use an ancestor approach!

> **child**: A child family may contain other child families or union families. Trees with this construction grow into descendant direction [...]

Then, for me, this is not a solution, because I can start my family tree from the top (I not yet know my "original ancestors").

Is there any solution?

Comment: The automated layout of `genealogytree` does not support arbitrary graph structures. The syntax allows to set up *annotated* mathematical tree structures as described by the documentation. Structures like *descendents of the grandparents* and so on have to be built by connecting several trees manually (see Tutorial 2.4).

Comment: maybe you want to have a look into the Solution of my Problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444668/genealogytree-how-to-model-my-cousins)