# {genealogytree} How to model my Cousins

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees, genealogytree, genealogy

I am working with the "genealogytree" package for a long time, but im struggling again about modeling my Cousins.

After i got Trouble Merging my multiple (completed) Family Trees ([Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419720/genealogytree-multiple-family-trees-with-unions)) with ~150 Nodes, i started to model from  a "superbaby" (below of the youngest living generation) and from a "superparent" (above the oldest generation i want to model). Where the root is either the superbaby or the supergrandfather (Father from all my Ancestors in the oldest Generation i want to model)

With the "superbaby"-attempt, im able to model my Cousins, but im having trouble putting my Uncle into my fathers family.

With the "superparent" im having a smiliar trouble.

Is there any Chance to Model my Cousins correctly ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,transform shape]
    \genealogytree[]
    {
        parent{                                        
            g[box={colback=green!20!white}]{invisible superbaby}
            parent{
                g[male]{My Brother}
                c[male,box={colback=yellow!80}]{Me}
                parent{
                    g[female]{Mother}
                    parent{
                        g[female]{Grandmother (Mother)}
                    }
                    parent{
                        g[male]{Grandfather (Mother)}
                    }
                }
                parent{
                    g[male]{Father}
                    parent{
                        g[female]{Grandmother (Father)}
                    }
                    parent{
                        g[male]{Grandfather (Father)}
                    }
                }
            }
            parent{
                g[male]{Cousin 1}
                c[male]{Cousin 2}
                p[female]{Aunt}
                p[male]{Uncle (Fathers Brother)}
            }
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And i also need to model my cousins child aswell as the Descendants from my grandmothers aunt an so on. So my genealogy tree have to contain several Nodes from different ancestor in my level.

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to go! I manually edit my Uncle to My Father-Parents Family:

```
add child=uncle to fam_grand,
```

This includes a small Issue with my Grandparents Position, so i have to adjust them myself manually:

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,transform shape]
    \genealogytree[
        %add parent=grandma to fam_uncle
        add child=uncle to fam_grand
    ]
    {
        parent{                                        
            g[box={colback=green!20!white}]{invisible superbaby}
            parent{
                g[male]{My Brother}
                c[male,box={colback=yellow!80}]{Me}
                parent[]{
                    g[female]{Mother}
                    parent{
                        g[female]{Grandmother (Mother)}
                    }
                    parent{
                        g[male]{Grandfather (Mother)}
                    }
                }
                parent[id=fam_grand,pivot shift=-2.4cm]{ %2.4cm = Node Size
                    g[male]{Father}
                    p[female]{Grandmother (Father)}
                    p[male]{Grandfather (Father)}
                }
            }
            parent[id=fam_uncle]{
                g[male]{Cousin 1}
                c[male]{Cousin 2}
                p[id=uncle,male]{Uncle (Fathers Brother)}
                parent{
                    g[female]{Aunt}
                    p[female]{Aunts Mother}
                    p[male]{Aunts Father}
                }
            }
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```